# Ubuntu 20.04.1 usb no longer functioning

Tags: usb, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04.1 abruptly stopped recognizing USB devices on the machine my kids use. Have tried with a mouse, a game controller, and a USB stick on different ports without success, all work when plugged into a different machine.

The computer is a Lenovo Yoga 900-131SK.

I have tried making each of the following changes to `/etc/default/grub`, updating grub, and then rebooting, without success:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force irqpoll"`
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"`
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"`

I also tried `chmod 777 /media/` without succcess.

I've seen a number of suggestions to check the BIOS to see whether USB is disabled there, but BIOS has been inaccessible (nonexistent?) on this machine since well before the problem emerged. (That's a Windows issue, apparently -- I was trying to set this up to dual-boot.)

Several programs were installed prior to the problem appearing: ri-li, kgeography, and childsplay. I've uninstalled all of them and rebooted with no change in behavior.

Output of `lsusb` with USB mouse plugged in is:
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub`
`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.`
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57e1 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Lenovo  EasyCamera`
`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

That covers every suggestion I've been able to find. Any other ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Try checking the logs, maybe you're having a problem with drivers. Maybe consider upgrading to 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Actually on 20.04.1. Will edit to reflect. Not entirely sure what to look for in the logs (I very much learn by trial and error), but `dmesg | grep USB` returns a number of "New USB device found" entries; `syslog` shows several entries: `usb: port power management may be unreliable`. That sounds like exactly the issue I keep encountering, except the proposed solution of editing various lines in `/etc/default/grub` haven't worked.

Comment: And yeah, no DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

Solved (at least enough). I edited `/etc/default/grub` to change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force irqpoll'` (as I had previously attempted) *and* swapped the USB port for the mouse. One of the ports now functions, but not the other, so presumably I was testing the mouse in the still non-functioning port. I'm not sure why that wasn't functioning, but it's not mission-critical, so I'm closing this.